# Проблема с обновлением системы под Debian

Tags: обновления, debian

Не могу обновить ОС и установить любую программу, так как при запуске обновления ссылается на IP, который не существует. Помогите, а то все уже облазил и нигде не могу найти этот IP. Подскажите, где я он может быть прописан.

Comment: Как запускаете обновление? что получаете в ответ?Ещё сюда нужен /etc/apt/sources.list луше так,     egrep -v "^#|^$" /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: Наверное я не совсем понятно выразился.. Запустите обновление таким образом:    apt-get update    apt-get upgradeВывод сюда.

Answer (score 1):

> sudo fuser -vki /var/lib/dpkg/lockИ зачем? если у него просто не верно прописаны репы, тебе сюда => [Список репозиториев Debian](http://linuxforum.ru/viewtopic.php?id=43)

Answer (score 0):

может это поможет:

```
sudo fuser -vki /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

(y/N) y

попробуйте,не обещаю но все может быть.